# continuous function on a circle without holomorphic continuation to the interior

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D^2\subset\mathbb{C}$ be the closed unit disc and $\mathbb{S}^1 = \partial{D^2}$. I'd like a continuous function $f:\mathbb{S^1}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, that can not be continued to a function $D^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ that is continuous on the whole $D^2$ and holomorphic in $int(D^2)$. I'd like to understand what sort of "obstacle" should I be looking for. As I understand, the function $f$ should not be holomorphic to start with. I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: What about $f(z)=1/z=\bar z$ on the unit circle?

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem. I guess I was looking for something continuous in the disc, therefore didn't see this one.

Comment: Well, certainly the function $f(z)=\bar z$ is continuous in the entire plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it extends (uniquely) to a harmonic function. Thos harmonic is holomorphic if and only if he Fourier series of f must is of form $\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n e^{i n \theta}$.